# Using global styles.scss to control :host of every Angular component

Tags: css, angular, sass, pseudo-class

I've noticed that **every** view in my application has a style file starting like this.

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
}
div.foo {
  background-color: red;
}
```

It seemed as a wise decision to reduce redundancy and move the general definition to *styles.scss*. Doing so, I noticed that, while the `DIV` styling continued to work as expected, the effect on the pseudo-selector vanished.

Googling gave me that [I can't reach the host element from **inside** the component](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors) but it doesn't say anything about altering it from **outside** of it (which my global *styles.scss* certainly is). I also found a blog on [Angular view encapsulation](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) where details are discussed in depth, however, without mention of the global *styles.scss*.

Summarizing, I've found a lot of info on handling `:host` and a lot of info on applying global *styles.scss*. However, I've seen rather limited intersection between them. Such an absence of an explicit confirmation implies often that it's infeasible or at least higly discouraged.

Have I misunderstood the point made in the docs? If so, how can I control the `:host` speudo-class from my global *styles.scss*? Or is it a special case of no-no and can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

A simple solution using CSS only - `:host>* { color: blue; }` in your root component.

*Note: This CSS rule will only design components at the first level, If you want to apply to all components of the app you will need to use the original answer*

**ORIGINAL**

I was looking for an elegant way to get what you are asking for, And the best way I've been able to accomplish this is by using SASS.
I did an experiment and saw when inheriting a SASS file with a `:host` definition, the `:host` selector refers to the component that inherits it.

After a try, the steps below works the same with CSS;

the steps (SCSS / CSS tested):

1. add new folder under `src` named `styling` (or whatever you want), add inside new file name `_base.scss` (note the underscore)
2. inside `_base.scss` add the style for `:host`
3. in your components `sass` style, at first line add `@import "~src/styling/base";`
4. That's it!

Comment: So there's no way to have it in the default *styles.scss* file? I'm asking because that file's definitions are automatically available without the requirement to import them. If I have a `div.bordered` defined in it and set that class on any `div`, I immediately get the styling.

Comment: You can use schematics to add the import to any generated component via CLI and enforce the import row in existing components
https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2

Comment: Right. I was hoping for a way that doesn't require the explicit `@import` statement in my components' SASS files. As it works now, declaring a style for a component/class, is available everywhere in the application without the explicit import. However, the pseudo-class isn't. And it bugs me.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten what's about the css selector `:host>* { color: blue; }` in your root component, i don't like this hack because it may have some problems with css inheritance but it worth a try

Comment: Hacky but nice. I can accept it. Please add it as an alternative to your answer so we can remove the comments. Let me know when it's done so I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten i also added a note the it will apply only on first level components, i will continue to think about a solution for the entire app, current now i am testing the a new way: build a dynamic css with a list of all components at runtime

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to define your own import paths for SASS like node_modules libraries, all you need to do is make a stylePreprocessorOptions entry in the options section of the angular.json file. You do not need to include everything using src\sass

```
angular.json
"options": {
  "outputPath": "dist/App",
  "index": "src/index.html",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
  "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "assets": [
    "src/favicon.ico",
    "src/assets"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "src/sass/styles.scss"
  ],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "src/sass"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": []
},
```

Now in your component styles simply import styles.scss. Don't include the file extension or an initial ~

```
@import './styles.scss';
```